# How to set date of input type="date" based on ng-model value

Tags: angularjs

I have a date in $scope. When the page loads I want the input type="date" field value to be set on the value in $scope.

```
<input class="form-control" type="date"
        ng-model="asso.formation_of_association"
        placeholder="" />
```

But I only see `dd-mm-yyy` on the input field

Answer (score 1):

You should show your code becouse I prepared an example and it works.

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="date" ng-model="date.formation_of_association">
  </div>
</div>

function myCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.asso = {
    'formation_of_association': '2018-06-21'
  };

}
```

Comment: @boo [_"It is impossible to change the format"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format). You can change the output instead, with a date filter. e.g. `<p>{{asso.formation_of_association | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</p>`

Comment: hey.. i think over 1.3v string won't be supported. that was my problem. i had date in string. @AlekseySolovey

Answer (score 0):

check the type of the `ng-model` value with `typeof`

if the `typeof` returns a `date` replace in your input file with type `date`